# error con un select2 delante de un modal

Tags: jquery, css, select2

Tengo el siguiente problema, al seleccionar el select2, las opciones se muestran debajo del modal ocultandose a vista del usuario, alguna forma de solucionarlo y mostrarlo delante del modal?

Intente con el siguiente codigo:

```
.select2{
  z-index: 999999;
}
```

Pero no funciono.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En general cuando se abre un modal éste se apropia de los eventos relacionados con clicks y teclas (por ejemplo, para cerrarse cuando apretes ESC o ENTER).

Como select2 crea su html dinámico en el `body` y queda fuera del modal, no es tomado en cuenta. Para esto, debes usar la opción [dropdownParent](https://select2.org/dropdown#dropdown-placement) pasándole el ID de tu modal:

```
$('#mySelect2').select2({
  dropdownParent: $('#myModal')
});
```

Con eso el contenido del dropdown de select2 queda dentro del nodo DOM del modal y debiera funcionar bien.